# XCode4 not showing available options under Build Settings properties

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

For some reason, after some days working with XCode4, it simply stopped showing the available value options for any properties under the 'Build Settings' configuration.

Let me show you:

[image]

As you can see, I'm not able to select the provisioning profile from all that it is installed under my machine. The very same happens to boolean values, and anything else.

Does anyone have any idea of what it's going on? Any configuration I must be doing on XCode4?

I tried reset all preferences (deleting the plist and caches), I uninstalled the whole Developer Tools and reinstalled. It hasn't solved anything.

**EDIT:** What I'm saying is that, instead of showing a combobox with all available options for that property, it just shows a textbox for me to fulfill. What I want in the example above is to show all Provisioning Profiles that are installed, instead of having me wondering around what is the correct profile name/code and type there.

Comment: Could it be that you have selected to show the basic settings only? There are two buttons "Basic" and "All" on the line below the "Build Settings" tab.

Comment: It is already selected the "All" option. It just shows more properties, doesn't correct the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED:** This is changed by Editor->Show Values (or Show Definitions)

Comment: What a simple fix compared to what I have been trying without luck until now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching a device (particularly if you selected a device SDK profile). Something similar was the case for 3.x Xcode.

Comment: this is not the case. I edited my original post for more information.